# Creating Table with Column Names from another table

Tags: tables

I want to create a table that will have two columns:

```
Table Name
Column Name
```

So I would read, say 3 tables, and for each table I would create a row for each column in that table, that would have the table name and the column name. So for example:

```
Account_Table
Account_id
Account_Name
Account_Address

Customer_Table
Customer_id
Customer_name
Customer_address

Merchandise_Table
Merch_Sku_number
Merch_Description
```

So the table I create would look like this:

```
Account_table     Account_id
Account_table     Account_name
Account_table     Account_address
Customer_table    Customer_id
Customer_table    Customer_name
```

And so on, get the idea?

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Sounds as merging relational databases ;-)

Comment: Oh, I forgot: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `pgfplotstable` could be useful here